# Impossible to use @graphql-codegen/cli correctly, Error: Cannot find module 'stream/web'

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows, graphql, apollo-server

I have some problems using graphql-codegen. Here's the best description I can give, hope it helps with the resolution.

My work environment:

- Windows 10
- Non-admin user
- NodeJS 16.0.0
- NPM 7.24.2
- Typescript 5.2.2
- Apollo server express 3.12.1
- GraphQL 15.8.0

The error is obtained when (according to the documentation) I init with this command: `npx graphql-code-generator init`

Note that for absolutely EVERY other NPM package I've used, I've never had ANY problems. Why then would graphql-codegen specifically be a problem? I don't know..

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:943
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'stream/web'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\node_modules\@graphql-tools\apollo-engine-loader\node_modules\@whatwg-node\fetch\dist\create-node-ponyfill.js
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\node_modules\@graphql-tools\apollo-engine-loader\node_modules\@whatwg-node\fetch\dist\node-ponyfill.js
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\node_modules\@graphql-tools\apollo-engine-loader\cjs\index.js
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\cjs\graphql-config.js
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\cjs\config.js
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\cjs\cli.js
- C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\cjs\bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:773:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at createNodePonyfill (C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\node_modules\@graphql-tools\apollo-engine-loader\node_modules\@whatwg-node\fetch\dist\create-node-ponyfill.js:31:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\random\Documents\gitlab\game-backend\node_modules\@graphql-codegen\cli\node_modules\@graphql-tools\apollo-engine-loader\node_modules\@whatwg-node\fetch\dist\node-ponyfill.js:3:19)     
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\node_modules\\@graphql-tools\\apollo-engine-loader\\node_modules\\@whatwg-node\\fetch\\dist\\create-node-ponyfill.js',        
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\node_modules\\@graphql-tools\\apollo-engine-loader\\node_modules\\@whatwg-node\\fetch\\dist\\node-ponyfill.js',
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\node_modules\\@graphql-tools\\apollo-engine-loader\\cjs\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\cjs\\graphql-config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\cjs\\config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\cjs\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\random\\Documents\\gitlab\\game-backend\\node_modules\\@graphql-codegen\\cli\\cjs\\bin.js'
  ]
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "game-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/src/index.js",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "serve": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q build/src/index.js\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "SomethingIDon'tWantToShow"
  },
  "author": "SomethingIDon'tWantToShow",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@graphql-tools/load": "^8.0.0",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^8.5.1",
    "@graphql-tools/utils": "^8.9.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.15",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.12.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.12.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^2.0.0",
    "keycloak-connect": "^22.0.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.11.0",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.7",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.5",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I tried:

- Run the `npx graphql-code-generator init` command with the terminal in Administrator mode, this changes nothing.
- Delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` folder and reinstall it with `npm install`, it doesn't change anything.
- Check that the files mentioned in the errors are present: They exist, also sames paths.
- Changing my version of NPM in more recent doesn't change anything.
- Change my version of NodeJS, I see no point in it because the other backend projects my colleague is working on have exactly the same configuration and 0 problems in his side.

Any idea?